# Changing the class of an element with onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to figure out how to change the class of an element when an OnClick is triggered via javascript.

Basically, I have the following code:

index.html

```
<div class="bottom_section">
 <div class="tab_section">
  <div class="tabing">
   <ul>
    <li id="active_news"><a onclick="ContentSwitch('News');">
     <img src="includes/t_news.png" width="23" height="81" alt="t_news">
    </a></li>
    <li id="active_events"><a onclick="ContentSwitch('Events');">
     <img src="includes/t_events.png" width="20" height="121" alt="t_events">
    </a></li>
    <li id="active_updates"><a onclick="ContentSwitch('Updates');">
     <img src="includes/t_updates.png" width="19" height="141" alt="t_updates">
    </a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

this list of images appears on the left of a box that switches the content shown in the box.

I have a class in my css:

```
.bottom_section .tabing li.active{background: #1ca1e3 url(tab_li_active.gif) repeat-x 0 0;}
```

That changes the background of the tab image to a darker shade to show that it's "clicked". So, I basically need to add a class="active" to the < li > tag if the tab is "selected".

I have the javascript code, which I found here on Stack Overflow to try and switch the class but it doesn't work.

```
function ContentSwitch(id) {
 if (id == "News") {
  if (document.getElementById("news_content").style.display = "none") {
   document.getElementById("news_content").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("active_news").className = document.getElementById("active_news").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )

   // Hide other content
   document.getElementById("events_content").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("updates_content").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 if (id == "Events") {
  if (document.getElementById("events_content").style.display = "none") {
   document.getElementById("events_content").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("active_events").className = document.getElementById("active_events").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )

   // Hide other content
   document.getElementById("news_content").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("updates_content").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 if (id == "Updates") {
  if (document.getElementById("updates_content").style.display = "none") {
   document.getElementById("updates_content").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("active_updates").className = document.getElementById("active_updates").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )

   // Hide other content
   document.getElementById("news_content").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("events_content").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

All the onclick works (the content is switched successfully) but the tab images do not switch. If I add manually the class="active" to the < li > tag, and click on any other tab the active goes away and doesn't come back, so the javascript is doing something.

what am I missing?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Er, why would that have anything to do with this question? FYI, none of the previous "answers" that were given on previous questions solved the issues, which I had expressed on those questions and to no avail, I did not receive further "answers" to those questions so I can't mark them "answered" unless I actually get them "answered", can I? Thanks.

Comment: did you output the return of the regexp process?

Comment: @John For example, [your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829151/passing-values-to-a-function-from-within-a-function-in-python) had five different users asking for clarification or suggesting improvement, and you never even responded to one of those comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks quite messy. Anyway try this:

```
document.getElementById("active_news").className = '';
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think you could just make this blank and it would remove it, that's where my issue was. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you use tree ids to identity tree tabs, active_news, active_events, active_updates
in the javascript it references news_content and events_content, should that references active_news, active_events ?

so the code should look like

```
    function ContentSwitch(id) {
 if (id == "News") {
  if (document.getElementById("active_news").style.display = "none") {
   document.getElementById("active_news").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("active_news").className = document.getElementById("active_news").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )

   // Hide other content
   document.getElementById("active_events").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("active_updates").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 if (id == "Events") {
  if (document.getElementById("active_events").style.display = "none") {
   document.getElementById("active_events").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("active_events").className = document.getElementById("active_events").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )

   // Hide other content
   document.getElementById("active_updates").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("active_news").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 if (id == "Updates") {
  if (document.getElementById("active_updates").style.display = "none") {
   document.getElementById("active_updates").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("active_updates").className = document.getElementById("active_updates").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )

   // Hide other content
   document.getElementById("active_events").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("active_news").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: the original code worked fine, as the actual content are named by a different ID. I definitely plan on cleaning it up a bit if I can...but for now, I just want to get the darn thing done. Thanks!